# What is the purpose of built-in FPGA with Intels new chip

Tags: fpga, intel

I know that Intel acquired Altera in 2015 and the new Intel chips include a built-in FPGA. But what is it for?

Comment: Which Intel chips? There's several applications where you would've had a CPU and an FPGA, and now you only need one chip.

Comment: Custom acceleration of state-machine behaviors.

Comment: @immibis [Xeon Scalable Processor 6138P](https://itpeernetwork.intel.com/intel-processors-fpga-better-together/), currently.

Comment: Too many transistors available now and not enough good ideas how to use all of them.

Comment: To run algorithms in their own "piplelines", a lot of companies (voip, video) that need data computed in real-time (micro seconds) off load the heaviest stuff to FPGA's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what is it for?

It's a bit early to say for sure. As of May 2018, Intel has only demonstrated one FPGA/CPU part (the [Xeon Scalable Processor 6138P](https://itpeernetwork.intel.com/intel-processors-fpga-better-together/)), and it's not yet shipping to the general public.

That all being said, the theoretical advantage of having an FPGA in the CPU package is high-speed, low-latency data transfers between the CPU and FPGA fabric (and, potentially, to connected devices). One of Intel's example applications is software-defined network switching, for instance.

Comment: A fast FPGA also gives you a on-the-fly changeable address decoder and memory mapper, but I think Intel has been doing that for a while.

Answer (score 2):

"Anything" you want for which you cant afford the MIPS otherwise.  There is a lot of effort in "non traditional" industries, such as Brokerages, that are using FPGAs/ASICs to execute trades faster, as latency equates to dollars.

Also, Intel is pushing the OpenCL (higher-level "Configurable Logic" language) for use in their (formerly Altera) tool flow, to lower the entry point for "consumer-side FPGA use".   This is not going to change the ASIC/FPGA commercial/professional world, but will allow consumers to create custom logic.  Like when you want to try and cheat on your non-server-side FPS game maybe(?)  ;)

Comment: OpenCL is "Open Computing Language", not "Configurable Logic" language. Its used for distributed computing across GPUs and CPUs, as well as to a certain extent FPGAs.

Comment: At first, I thought your example of low-latency trading using FPGA was made-up bullshit. Then I looked it up and there seems to be actual companies developing this kind of things. And now, I don't want to live on this planet anymore... Anyway, have an upvote.

Comment: Oh, my bad on acronym translation, should have googled it... same-same, it's an HLS as far as I am concerned :/  @dim, I am surprised Axe Capital hasn't cornered it yet :)